# Angular JS: Passing input parameters in HTTP service (POST)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm new to Angular JS and have been stuck in this problem.

```
<body class="homepage" ng-app="angularApp">

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($fruits as $fruit) 
            <!-- looping -->
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$fruit->id}}" ng-model="testParameter">
            <button  ng-click="testClick(testParameter)" class="adding_item_to_cart">Add to Cart</button>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <p ng-bind="testBind"></p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);
    angularApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.testClick = function(id) {
             $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "/fruits/add/".id
             }).then(function addSucces(response) {
                $scope.testBind =response.data;
             }, function addError(response) {
                $scope.testBind = "Error!";
             });
        }
     });
</script>

</body>
```

What I've been trying to do is to send a parameter as an input value of HTTP request when the `testClick` is invoked to run the POST method, based on which `fruit` (i.e. the contents of the for-loop) has been chosen. (In this example, I'm trying to run a Route method of Laravel 5.2).

So far, I have found some postings on Stackoverflow, which are apparently relevant to this task. The code above is modified several times, following the advice of those postings.

I **do** understand this causes an error, but I'm clueless as to what is actually wrong and what I need to do instead.

ANY advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
url : "/fruits/add/".id
```

should be this:

```
url : "/fruits/add/" + id
```

You're saying 'gimme the id property of a string' - that aint gonna work!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, however, this causes another error. The POST method is not properly run, since the URL is rendered as `http://localhost:8000/fruits/addundefined `.

Comment: So it looks like your testParameter is not being set then

Answer (score 0):

In `$http` url key there is improper concatenation done, see following fixed code:

```
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "/fruits/add/"+ id
             }).then(function addSucces(response) {
                $scope.testBind =response.data;
             }, function addError(response) {
                $scope.testBind = "Error!";
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, however, this causes another error. The POST method is not properly run, since the URL is rendered as `http://localhost:8000/fruits/addundefined `.

Comment: apparently it means `testParameter` is not correctly passed which causes `id` to be undefined and url becomes the one you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

@YMD - not sure if this is so relevant now, your question has probably been answered by now but since you have not marked any as the right answer, I am responding with this. Please mark it as correct answer if it answers your question.

The **testParameter** is undefined in the controller. either use $scope from within the controller - **$scope.testParameter=" ";** or bind it to some object and use *object.testParameter*.

Unless the View passes the variable to the controller, the controller has no way of knowing about it so, testParameter remains just a View scoped variable, **with no value assigned to it**, and hence, **undefined**.